# Shiny Slick R carousel with internal links to tab panels

Tags: r, shiny, carousel, navbar, slickr

I would like to create a shiny navbarPage dashboard that has a slickR carousel of images on the landing page. Each image should have an action button superimposed that links to a different tabPanel.
It should basically look like this:
[Screenshot of toy app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ypog.png)
Here is reproducible toy example that doesn't do the job:`

```
library(shiny)
library(slickR)
# ui
ui <- navbarPage(title = "", id = "pageid",
                 tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                             tab1 <- tabPanel(title="Tab 1", value="tab1",
                                              fluidRow(
                                                slickROutput("slickr1"),
                                                h1("Title", style =
                                                     "position: relative;
                                                      margin-top:-43%;
                                                      color:#4BACC6;
                                                      font-size:30px;
                                                      text-align: center"),
                                                div(actionButton("action1", "Action",
                                                                 style="position: relative;
                                                                  margin-top: 15%;
                                                                  color:#FFFEFB;
                                                                  background-color:#4BACC6;
                                                                  border-color:#4BACC6;"), 
                                                    align="center"),
                                                                            )),
                             tab2 <- tabPanel(title="Tab 2", value="tab2"),
                             tab3 <- tabPanel(title="Tab 3", value="tab3")
                 )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$slickr1 <- renderSlickR({
    slick1 <- slick_list(slick_div(
      nba_player_logo$uri[1:3],
      type = "img", links = NULL)
    )
    slickR(slick1) +
      settings(dots = TRUE,
               autoplay = TRUE)
  })
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs",
                      selected = "tab2")
  })
}
```

`
This code superimposes the same action button and title on all three images on the carousel and I can't get slickR to run through both images and action buttons.

I have tried to create a second slick_div within the slick_list that runs through three different action buttons, like this:
`

```
# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  buttons <- list(actionButton("action1", "Action1"),
                 actionButton("action2", "Action2"),
                 actionButton("action3", "Action3"))                         
  output$slickr1 <- renderSlickR({
    slick1 <- slick_list(slick_div(
      nba_player_logo$uri[1:3],
      type = "img", links = NULL),
    slick_div(
      buttons,
      css = htmltools::css(display = "inline"),
      links = NULL)
  )
    slickR(slick1) +
      settings(dots = TRUE,
               autoplay = TRUE)
  })
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs",
                      selected = "tab2")
  })
}
```

`
But it somehow just ends up stacking all the images on top each other for slide 1 and all action buttons next to each other on slide 2, rather than running through them one by one with one image and one action button on each slide.

Alternatively, I would also be open to having the entire image link to a different tab and I thought about using the "links" option in slick_div (set to NULL in the toy example above), but I'm struggling to determine a url for each of tabs that I could assign to "links".

I'm new to shiny and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the problem with your first app? I ran it and it seems OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand. Is it what you want?

```r
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

css <- "
.slidetitle {
  position: relative;
  color: #4BACC6;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slidebutton {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -15%;
  color: #FFFEFB;
  background-color: #4BACC6;
  border-color: #4BACC6;
}
"


# ui
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "SlickR with buttons", 
  id = "tabs",
  header = tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  tabPanel(
    title= "Tab 1", value = "tab1",
    fluidRow(
      slickR(slick_list(
        tags$div(
          tags$h1("Title 1", class = "slidetitle"),
          tags$img(
            src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/31/22/08/lion-3576045__340.jpg",
            height = 500
          ),
          actionButton(
            "action1", "Action 1", class = "slidebutton"
          ),
          align = "center"
        ),
        tags$div(
          tags$h1("Title 2", class = "slidetitle"),
          tags$img(
            src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/02/27/15/35/lion-17335__340.jpg",
            height = 500
          ),
          actionButton(
            "action2", "Action 2", class = "slidebutton"
          ),
          align = "center"
        ),
        tags$div(
          tags$h1("Title 3", class = "slidetitle"),
          tags$img(
            src = "https://www.aprenderjuntos.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/LEON-SERIO-.jpg",
            height = 500
          ),
          actionButton(
            "action3", "Action 3", class = "slidebutton"
          ),
          align = "center"
        )
      )) + settings(autoplay = TRUE, dots = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Tab 2", value = "tab2",
    tags$h1("TAB 2")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Tab 3", value = "tab3",
    tags$h1("TAB3")
  )
)

# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    updateNavbarPage(session, "tabs", selected = "tab2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To have the title on top of the image, use this CSS:

```css
.slidecontainer {
  position: relative;
}
.slidetitle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #4BACC6;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.slidebutton {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -15%;
  color: #FFFEFB;
  background-color: #4BACC6;
  border-color: #4BACC6;
}
```

and add the class `slidecontainer` to the `div` elements:

```r
      slickR(slick_list(
        tags$div(
          class = "slidecontainer",
          tags$h1("Title 1", class = "slidetitle"),
          tags$img(
            src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/31/22/08/lion-3576045__340.jpg",
            height = 500
          ),
          actionButton(
            "action1", "Action 1", class = "slidebutton"
          ),
          align = "center"
        ),
        ......
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly! I just have one follow-up question: How do I get the title to display in front/on top of the image instead of above? Thanks again!!

Comment: @DanB See my answer, I've just edited it.